# What's wrong with this simple cuda program?

Tags: cuda

I'm just trying to use CUDA to blank an image. But "before" and "after" I get the same original image. Can't figure out the problem.

sumKernel.cu:

```
#include "sumKernel.h"

__global__ void _sumKernel(char *image, int width, int height, char *kernel, int kerwidth, int kerheight) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    image[idx] = 0;
}

void sumKernel(char *image, int width, int height, char *kernel, int kerwidth, int kerheight) {
    dim3 blocks(1);
    dim3 threads(width*height);
    _sumKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(image, width, height, kernel, kerwidth, kerheight);
}
```

sumKernel.h:

```
void sumKernel(char *image, int width, int height, char *kernel, int kerwidth, int kerheight);
```

main.cpp:

```
findCudaDevice(argc, (const char **)argv);

Mat image = imread("a.jpg");
Mat gray; cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
imshow("before", gray);

char *gray_g;
cudaMalloc((void **)&gray_g, gray.size().area());
cudaMemcpy(gray_g, gray.data, sizeof(char)*gray.size().area(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

char kernel[9];
char *kernel_g;
cudaMalloc((void **)&kernel_g, sizeof(char)*9);

sumKernel(gray_g, gray.cols, gray.rows, kernel, 3, 3);

cudaMemcpy(gray.data, gray_g, sizeof(char)*gray.size().area(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

imshow("after", gray);
waitKey(0);

cudaFree(kernel);
cudaFree(gray_g);
```

Comment: Please [check](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) all your API calls for errors. Most likely is that your block size of width*height threads is too large for a single block.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: @seilgu: Please write a short answer containing your solution/resolution and post it as an answer (which is OK). Later you will be able to accepted. This gets the question off the unanswered list and makes the solution easier to find by search for the next person who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting my comment as an answer)

Please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) all your API calls for errors. Most likely is that your block size of width*height threads is too large for a single block.